# MemCpy on a vector of structs

Tags: c++, windows, memcpy, memory-mapped-files

I have used MapVirtualFile to map a file under Window using C++ VS2010.
The void is

```
  void*                   m_pVoiceData;
```

I would now like to fill a vector of structs with the data.

The struct is

```
struct udtPitchmark
{
    unsigned long ByteStart;
    unsigned long ByteCount;
    unsigned long F0;
};

struct udtPitchmarks
{
    vector<udtPitchmark>Pitchmarks;
};
```

I have been using

```
void clsMapping::FeedPitchmarksFromMap(udtPitchmarks &uAudioInfo,unsigned long int uBytePos)
{

    unsigned int iCountPM;
    memcpy(&iCountPM, &((char*)(m_pVoiceData))[uBytePos],sizeof(unsigned long));

    uAudioInfo.Pitchmarks.resize(iCountPM);

    for (unsigned int i=0;i<iCountPM;i++)
    {
        iBytePos+=sizeof(unsigned long);
        unsigned long int iByteStart;
        memcpy(&iByteStart, &((char*)(m_pVoiceData))[iBytePos],4);

        iBytePos+=sizeof(unsigned long);
        unsigned long int iByteCount;
        memcpy(&iByteCount, &((char*)(m_pVoiceData))[iBytePos],4);

        iBytePos+=sizeof(unsigned long);
        unsigned int iF0;
        memcpy(&iF0, &((char*)(m_pVoiceData))[iBytePos],4);

        uAudioInfo.Pitchmarks[i].ByteStart =iByteStart;
        uAudioInfo.Pitchmarks[i].ByteCount =iByteCount;
        uAudioInfo.Pitchmarks[i].F0 =iF0;
    }
}
```

There are 3 memcpy's involved for every pitchmark.
But I hope that I can read ALL the pitchmarks at once.
However I am not sure how to do that.

The structs where stored like this:

```
vector<udtPitchmarks>::iterator it = nPitchmarks.Content().begin();
for (;it != nPitchmarks.Content().end(); ++it)
{
    unsigned int iCountPMs = it->Pitchmarks.size();
    fwrite(&iCountPMs,sizeof(unsigned int),1,outfile);

    vector<udtPitchmark>::iterator it2 = it->Pitchmarks.begin();
    for(;it2 != it->Pitchmarks.end(); ++it2)
    {
        fwrite(&it2->ByteStart,sizeof(unsigned long),1,outfile);
        fwrite(&it2->ByteCount,sizeof(unsigned long),1,outfile);
        fwrite(&it2->F0,sizeof(unsigned long),1,outfile);
    }
}
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: Use an `unsigned long[3]`, then you can fill it in one go.

Comment: I edited my post so that all 3 members are unsigned long now. Let's assume there are 10 pitchmarks... Can you post a sample of how I can fill them all in one rush?

Comment: Is that fine? memcpy(&uAudioInfo.Pitchmarks[0],&((char*)(m_pVoiceData))[iBytePos],sizeof(unsigned long)*3*10);

Comment: Not really, you're not guaranteed how the memory for the object is laid out.

Comment: Do you have a better idea? I am not sure why you suggest that in the first place then. Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: How portable do you need the code to be?

Comment: The better idea is to use an array...

Comment: @tmighty Pretty sure me meant `typedef unsigned long udtPitchmark[3];` or something similar, and I tend to agree.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Portability is very important to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can read whole udtPitchmark structure at once

```
m_pVoiceData = (char *)m_pVoiceData + sizeof(unsigned int); // size field
```

`memcpy( &uAudioInfo.Pitchmarks[i],  (udtPitchmark *)m_pVoiceData + i, sizeof udtPitchmark );`

or whole vector:

`memcpy( &uAudioInfo.Pitchmarks[0],  (udtPitchmark *)m_pVoiceData, sizeof(udtPitchmark ) * iCountPM);`

Comment: I have tried memcpy( &uAudioInfo.Pitchmarks[0], &((udtPitchmark *)(m_pVoiceData))[iBytePos], sizeof(udtPitchmark ) * iCountPM); now, which is close to your suggestion and also included the byte position where the structs reside, but I am getting an exception here. Are you sure you are right?

Comment: I have now also posted the way I stored the data.

Comment: Oh, okay. And how should I then define where the data starts?

Comment: ((udtPitchmark *)(m_pVoiceData))[iBytePos] means (m_pVoiceData + iBytePos * sizeof( udtPitchmark )),

but   
((char *)(m_pVoiceData))[iBytePos] means (m_pVoiceData + iBytePos * sizeof( char )). It seems to me you are not aware of it. 

add 4 before using m_pVoiceData as udtPitchmark *. and you don't need iBytePos.

Comment: But the data does not start at the beginning of the file. It may be located in the middle of the file or so. I have written other stuff to the file as well. Let's assume the data that we talk about starts at byte position 1000. Can you edit your sample to reflect that?

Comment: suppose m_pVoiceData points to the begin of the file.

`uAudioInfo.Pitchmarks.resize(iCountPM);
memcpy( &uAudioInfo.Pitchmarks[0], (char *)m_pVoiceData + 1000, sizeof(udtPitchmark) * iCountPM )`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37678/discussion-between-light-keeper-and-tmighty)

Comment: You already helped me very much, it works fine now. I wanted to avoid writing thanks, but anyway here it is now: Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you lay your data out as an array, you can write to it in one go. Accessor functions could help you maintain a readable interface:

```
struct Pitchmark
{
    unsigned long data[3];

    unsigned long & start() { return data[0]; }
    unsigned long & count() { return data[1]; }
    unsigned long & f0()    { return data[2]; }

    unsigned char * ptr() { return static_cast<unsigned char *>(data); }
};

Pitchmark pm;
memcpy(pm.ptr(), m_pVoiceData, sizeof pm.data);
```